# Looping through an unknown data structure (array/object) in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

All,

I am really struggling with this as I am not even sure the data structure.

Here is what I see in the console when I output it.

```
console.log('testjhp ', data);
```

Which gives me this

```
{knownFields: Array(12)}
knownFields: Array(12)
0: {id: "C#", label: "Customer Number", required: false, enabled: true}
1: {id: "R#", label: "Reference Number", required: true, enabled: true}
2: {id: "JC", label: "Job City", required: true, enabled: true}
3: {id: "CN", label: "Customer Name / Builder Name", required: true, 
enabled: true}
4: {id: "JN", label: "Job Name", required: true, enabled: true}
5: {id: "JS", label: "Job State", required: true, enabled: true}
6: {id: "JZ", label: "Job Zip", required: false, enabled: true}
7: {id: "CA2", label: "Cust Addr2", required: false, enabled: true}
8: {id: "JA2", label: "Job Address2", required: false, enabled: true}
9: {id: "CA1", label: "Cust Addr1", required: true, enabled: true}
10: {id: "JA1", label: "Job Address1", required: true, enabled: true}
11: {id: "FSD", label: "First Ship Date", required: true, enabled: true}
```

I am not sure even what this is.  I believe it is an array of JSON objects but if that is the case, how come I cannot reference them by typing 'knownFields[0]'?

Can some kind soul expand on this a bit more and the best way to loop through it?

Thx
jonpfl

Comment: because it would be `data.knownFields[0]`

Comment: Arghhhh, I did have data.knowfields BUT as you can see, I typed it wrong!!!

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is returned is an object with 'knownFields' as a property. 'knownFields' then corresponds to an array of objects.

You can access knownFields using:

```
objName["knownFields"]
//or
objName.knownFields
```

You can further access the array using:

```
objName["knownFields"][index]
//or
objName.knownFields[index]
```

To simplify things, I would assign the result from obj["knownFields"] to a variable.

Hope this helps!